# C++11: inconsistent warnings for out-of-order instance member initialization

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code crashes, raising `std::bad_alloc` or sometimes `std::logic_error`.

```
#include <string>

class Crasher {
public:
    Crasher() : value(default_value) {}
private:
    std::string value;
    const std::string default_value = "default is yours";
};


int main(void) {
    Crasher();
}
```

I believe the reason is that the members are initialized out of order, and when `value` is being intialized in initializer list, `default_value` hasn't yet been initialized.

However, I don't get any compiler warnings or errors with `-Wall` enabled. However if I change `value` and `default_value` to a POD type like `int`, then I get a warning from `g++`:

```
$ g++ -Wall crasher.cpp 
crasher2.cpp: In constructor ‘Crasher::Crasher()’:
crasher2.cpp:5:23: warning: ‘*<unknown>.Crasher::default_value’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    5 |     Crasher() : value(default_value) {}
      |
```

Why do I not get a warning when the type is `std::string`? Is this a compiler problem, or a quirk of the language?

Comment: Your surmise is correct but this is the way the language is _defined_: The order of initialization is not the order initializers appear, but the order of declaration.  It can bite you, as you just discovered, but once you learn the rule you have no further problems.  Frequently your IDE (if you use one) can warn you this might occur, and even rearrange your initializers for you.

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug. It ought to warn you. But, these warnings are not required by the standard, so it may be a lower priority for developers.

For fixing real code that is like this you might try making that `default_value` static. Then it should be initialized on first use and be more efficient too.

Comment: clang++ does give a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializing one `int` from another performs an **lvalue-to-rvalue conversion** on the source.  If that’s uninitialized, the behavior is undefined.  Initializing one object of class type from another does not do so—it calls a constructor, which merely binds a **reference** to the source.  That’s not undefined even if the source is out of lifetime, although typical copy constructors will of course exhibit undefined behavior in that case.  Whether you get a warning then depends on what analysis the compiler does after any **inlining** of the constructor.  With the default of no optimization, getting no warning is understandable.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation, Davis. I think I understand, though I'd like to dig a bit deeper. Do you happen to have a source for this information?

Comment: @Tom: Well, binding a reference is pretty obvious from how constructors are declared; reading a scalar to copy it is equally plain.  The UB is just the usual [basic.indet]/2.